# $timeout "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am attempting to use timeout to offset the resize trigger by a couple of mili seconds so that it works when I maximise the window. Unfortunately I am getting undefined is not a function:

```
angular.element(window).resize(function() {
    var newBreakpoint = getBreakpoint();
    var previousBreakpoint = null;

    if (newBreakpoint != currentBreakpoint) {
        previousBreakpoint = currentBreakpoint;
        currentBreakpoint = newBreakpoint;
    }

    var currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;

    var broadcastResize = function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('windowResize', currentBreakpoint, previousBreakpoint, currentWindowWidth);
    }       

    $timeout(broadcastResize, 150);

});
```

Within this directive:

```
adminLayoutDirectives.directive('viewFrame', [function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    return {
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            var width = function() {
                return $element.width();
            } 

            var getBreakpoint = function() {
                var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;

                if(windowWidth < 768) {
                    return 'extra small';
                } else if (windowWidth >= 768 && windowWidth < 992) {
                    return 'small';
                } else if (windowWidth >= 992 && windowWidth < 1200) {
                    return 'medium';
                } else if (windowWidth >= 1200) {
                    return 'large';
                }                   
            }

            currentBreakpoint = getBreakpoint();

            angular.element(window).resize(function() {
                var newBreakpoint = getBreakpoint();
                var previousBreakpoint = null;

                if (newBreakpoint != currentBreakpoint) {
                    previousBreakpoint = currentBreakpoint;
                    currentBreakpoint = newBreakpoint;
                }

                var currentWindowWidth = window.innerWidth;

                var broadcastResize = function() {
                    $scope.$broadcast('windowResize', currentBreakpoint, previousBreakpoint, currentWindowWidth);
                }       

                $timeout(broadcastResize, 150);

            }); 
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of

```
adminLayoutDirectives.directive('viewFrame', [function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout)
```

do

```
adminLayoutDirectives.directive('viewFrame', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$timeout', function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
```

enjoy

Comment: I get `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- viewFrameDirective`

Comment: Remove the `$scope` from `function($scope, $rootScope, $timeout)`

Comment: adminLayoutDirectives.directive('viewFrame', [ '$rootScope', '$timeout', function($rootScope, $timeout) {